# Excluding NULL or EMPTY values for certain fields

Tags: mysql

I wanted to skip blank data in MySQL.

My sample query won't work:

```
SELECT * FROM burger WHERE mayonnaise=1 AND pickle<>'.$yon.' AND ketchup IS NOT NULL AND ketchup<> '' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5
```

I want to skip data which is stored as blank.

```
id     mayonnaise   pickle   ketchup         
1      1              y
2      1              n        1
3      1              y
4      1              y
5      1              y        1
```

Comment: any chance you have whitespaces there? you can try `ketchup is not null and TRIM(ketchup) <> ''`

Answer (score 1):

I would do the following to handle both `Null` and empty values:

```
trim(coalesce(ketchup, ''))<>''
```

Answer (score -1):

Try regular expressions: `SELECT * FROM burger WHERE mayonnaise=1 AND pickle<>'.$yon.' AND ketchup REGEXP '[0-9]+' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5`, assuming `ketchup` only has numeric values. This would also filter out values which are non-numeric (and decimals) though, so depends on the datatype of `ketchup`.